# registerForRemoteNotificationTypes Additional information for users. Can it be displayed?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I registerForRemoteNotificationTypes On the app is there any way that 
i can give the user more information about the types of notification they will receive

IE `@"Accept to receive notifications of in-show special offers, discounts & special events"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be asking two different things:

- Can I ask the user before calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes which types they would like to receive?

or

- Can I give the user some context about why I'm going to ask for APNS permissions (i.e. what I'm going to use them for) before the APNS pop up is shown?

Both are possible.

To do 1 you could ask the user using your own UI which types of alert they want (sound / badge / alert) and then call the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types with types set per the user request

To do 2 you can certainly present some pages - like welcome screens - that explain that you are about to ask for permission and why the user should accept the request. And then after this explanation call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes

From my perspective, I think 2 is best practice, and substantially increases the chance that the user will accept the APNS request (the same goes for Location services).

Comment: Thanks thats great i will use option 2 on that one

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** Change the Text For Default Notification Alert,

You can use Trick like first with custom UIAlertView with additional information, After it You can ask for default Notification permission alert. But this will show two alert so  may user will not like it.

Comment: i just thought of that. so i have pulled the idea. and also it was showing every time the app started.

Comment: but you can store some variable for checking is app loads first time in NSUserDefaults than you have to show alert.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not change notification type as per your requirement.

The default notifications can not be changed. If you need to customize notification then change json data and show alert as per your requirement when the `receiveRemoteNotification` is called.